# PrimeFaces selectOneMenu style change

Tags: css, primefaces, selectonemenu

How to change PrimeFaces `selectOneMenu` style to the standard HTML style?

I thought I could leave `.ui-selectonemenu` and `.ui-selectonemenu-label` empty and magic is done. It's not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a default `<select><option ...></select>` HTML drop down, simply use the core JSF `h:selectOneMenu` in stead of the PrimeFaces variant.

If you really need to use the PrimeFaces variant, it will be a matter of styling it to your needs. Styling it to the default HTML `select` element will be hard, since it is OS and browser dependent.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to use editable functionality from primefaces.